# How to load data in handsontable spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, json, handsontable

**Hi Please help in loading data to handsontable sreadsheet
I am trying to add like this getting "#bad Value#" in column .**

```
$("#benefitDT").handsontable({

    data: benefitData(),
    // colWidths: [55, 127, 127, 147, 157, 147, 147, 147],
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: ["Name", "Yes/No", "Add/Nil", "Nil/Multiple", "Field Name", "Value", "Information"],
    stretchH: 'all',
    startRows: 5,
    fillHandle: true,
    columns: [
    {
    readOnly:true
    },
    {
    type: 'checkbox',
    checkedTemplate: 'yes',
    uncheckedTemplate: 'no'
    // source: ["Nil", "Add"]
    },
    {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ["Nil", "Add"]
    },
    {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ["Nil", "Multiple"]
    },
    {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ["Select", "No of Passenger", "No Of Cylinders", "No Of Doors"]
    },
    {
    type: 'numeric',
    format: '$ 0,0[.]00',
    language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
    },
    {

    }
    ],
    minSpareRows: 1
    });
```

**I am trying to get the data from web service and creating 
a array object and returning the same**

```
    function benefitData() {
    var obj = new Array();
    var ncbData = [];
    XXXXXXXX_apps.GetBenefits(function (arg) {
    if (arg.length > 0) {

    for (var i=1; i < arg.length - 1; i++) {
    var temp = [arg[i].split("|")[2], "yes", "Nil", "Nil", "Select", 12, 13];

    }

    }

    }
    return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in json format

```
  Public Function GetRates(ByVal ratesheetID As String) As String
            Dim alObj As New ArrayList()
            Dim dt As DataSet = xxxxxxxxx.GetAllRates(ratesheetID)
            Dim ratelist As New List(Of Rates)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim rate As New Rates()
                rate.YEAR = dr("YEAR")
                rate.AGENCYRATE = dr("AGENCYRATE")
                rate.AGENCYLOADING = dr("AGENCYLOADING")
                rate.AGENCYMINIPREMIUM = dr("AGENCYMINIPREMIUM")
                rate.NONAGENCYRATE = dr("NONAGENCYRATE")
                rate.NONAGENCYLOADING = dr("NONAGENCYLOADING")
                rate.NONAGENCYMINPREMIUM = dr("NONAGENCYMINPREMIUM")
                rate.EXCESS = dr("EXCESS")
                ratelist.Add(rate)

            Next
            Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim _JsonString = jss.Serialize(ratelist)
            Return _JsonString
        End Function
```

Using jquery page on load get the data into json format
setup your column style s per your data types and controls in spreadsheet.
After setting the spreadsheet setting according to your data load the data.

```
 function GenerateRateSheet() {
        var obj = new Array();
        var ncbData = [];
        loading("start");
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.GetRates($("#hdRID").val(), function (obj1) {
            debugger;
            var arg = $.parseJSON(obj1);
            if (arg.length > 0) {
                debugger;
                $("#rateDT").handsontable({
                    //   data: obj,
                    colHeaders: true,
                    colHeaders: ["YEAR", "Agency Rate (%)", "Agency Loading", "Agency MP", "Non Agency Rate (%)", "Non Agency Loading", "Non Agency MP", "Excess/Deductible"],
                    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
                    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
                    colWidths: [100, 150, 110, 100, 175, 160, 130, 180],
                    startRows: 6,
                    startCols: 8,
                    contextMenu: { items: { 'row_above': {}, 'row_below': {}, 'remove_row': {}, 'undo': {}, 'redo': {}} },
                    columnSorting: {
                        column: 1,
                        sortOrder: true
                    },
                    persistentState: true,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "YEAR",
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            type: 'numeric'
                            //readOnly: true
                        },
                        { data: "AGENCYRATE",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00%',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
                        }
                        ,
                        { data: "AGENCYLOADING",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0,0[.]00',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //i18n: use this for EUR (German)
                            //more locales available on numeraljs.com
                        },
                        { data: "AGENCYMINIPREMIUM",
                            //    data: "Agency MP",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0,0[.]00',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
                        },
                        { data: "NONAGENCYRATE",
                            //  data: "Non Agency Rate (%)",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00%',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //i18n: use this for EUR (German)
                            //more locales available on numeraljs.com
                        },
                        { data: "NONAGENCYLOADING",
                            //  data: "Non Agency Loading",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0,0[.]00',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
                        },
                        { data: "NONAGENCYMINPREMIUM",
                            //   data: "Non Agency MP", 
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0,0[.]00',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //i18n: use this for EUR (German)
                            //more locales available on numeraljs.com
                        },
                        {
                            data: "EXCESS",
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0,0[.]00',
                            allowInvalid: false,
                            language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
                        }
                        ]
                });

                $("#rateDT").handsontable("loadData", arg);
                loading("end");
            }
        },
        function (arg) {
            $("#divResult").html('<div class="alert"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Warning!</strong> Internal Server Error.</div>');
        });
    }
```

//Hope it will help if not then try to break the solution i  small piece and then try.because of lack of time i putted every thing.